# Stack implementation with StackInterface

Tags: java, stack

The code that I wrote is as follows:

```
public  class Astack implements StackInterface {
private int sz;
private Object[] a;
private int topPosition = -1;
public Astack(int sz){
   a = new Object[sz];
   this.sz = sz;
}
public int size(){
return topPosition+1;
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
  if(topPosition == -1){
  return true;
}
  return false;
}
public void push(Object element) throws StackFullException{
  if(topPosition+1 == sz){
    throw new StackFullException("Stack Full.");
  }
  a[++topPosition] = element;
}
public Object top() throws StackEmptyException{
  if(topPosition == -1){
    throw new StackEmptyException("Stack already Empty");
  }
return a[topPosition];
}
public Object pop() throws StackEmptyException{
  if(topPosition == -1){
    throw new StackEmptyException("Stack already Empty");
  }
  return a[topPosition--];
}
}
```

The `StackInterface` that I wrote:

```
public interface StackInterface{
    public int size();
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public Object top() throws StackEmptyException;
    public void push(Object element) throws StackFullException;
    public Object pop() throws StackEmptyException;
}
```

Comment: Is this a [tag:homework] problem? Is `StackInterface` given to you, or did you write it too? Could you also include it in the question?

Comment: @200_success.I -  is not a homework problem. I also wrote `StackInterface`. I just wanted to use stack the traditional way than using Stack java class. I have added the interface that i wrote in the question above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> private int sz;
> ```

Rather than call this `sz`, consider calling it `capacity`.  Writing out whatever name is easier to read, and `capacity` makes it clearer that it is potential size not current size.  But you don't actually need to store it.  It's already stored as `a.length`.

```
public Astack(int capacity){
    a = new Object[capacity];
}
```

See, more readable.

> ```
> public int size(){
> return topPosition+1;
> }
> ```

It's more customary to track the number of items in the stack, not the top position.

```
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

Put those together.

```
public class Astack implements StackInterface {

    private Object[] a;
    private int count = 0;

    public Astack(int capacity){
        a = new Object[capacity];
    }

    public int size(){
        return count;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return count == 0;
    }

    public void push(Object element) throws StackFullException {
        if (count == a.length) {
          throw new StackFullException("Stack Full.");
        }

        a[count] = element;
        count++;
    }

    public Object top() throws StackEmptyException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new StackEmptyException("Stack already Empty");
        }

        return a[count - 1];
    }

    public Object pop() throws StackEmptyException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new StackEmptyException("Stack already Empty");
        }

        --count;
        return a[count];
    }

}
```

Now each line only does one thing.  We don't update `count` and `return` something else on the same line.

We don't have to do extra math to turn `topPosition` into what we really want.

```
    private Object[] a;
    private int count = 0;

    public Astack(int capacity){
        a = new Object[capacity];
    }
```

In the future, you may want to replace these lines with just

```
    private List<T> stack = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then the default constructor works, so you don't need to define one.  And we don't need to maintain a `count`, as `stack.size()` will return the current count.

We can get rid of the `StackFullException`, as the `ArrayList` will automatically resize as necessary.

And we can stop casting to and from `Object`, as generics don't require that.

Comment: I think `top` should return `a[count - 1]`.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't really much to optimize here, but there are definitely improvements you can make regarding usability and coding style.

- use generics instead of Object, otherwise the stack is difficult to use in practice.
- in practice, you would probably want a stack to increase its size automatically instead of throwing an exception.
- your indentation is not consistent, making your code difficult to read.
- you need more vertical whitespace, for example before a new method
- your variable names could use improvement. What's a `sz`? What's an `a`? What's an `Astack`?

Comment: I do intend my code properly but when i paste it here it just gets distorted which is very irritating. Apart from that you are right and +1 for the tips :)

Comment: Also, the use of checked exceptions makes this very unusable at the call site because you need `try catch` everywhere.

Comment: @Clashsoft definitely. But I wasn't sure if OP maybe extended eg `RuntimeException`, making the exceptions unchecked (which would seem like a good option here).

Comment: @Clashsoft - That's correct. I am using couple of `try catch` blocks here.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an if statment just this:

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
  //Returns a boolean value
  return topPosition==-1;
}
```

When comparing 2 variables you get a `boolean`result